# CSV Parsing, to read the input for Junit Testing line by line

Tags: java, json, csv, junit

This is my code for reading the csv file line by line for performing the Junit Test for HTTP request. But I am able to test only alternate data ie: first data is read then second is skipped, then third is read, fourth skipped and so on from CSV file, kindly help me with the code if there is is any problem in it

```
package testingpack;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;


import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.csvreader.CsvReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Test;


public class testcase {

@Test
public void test() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, JSONException {

    String output = null;
    String url="";
    String testJson;
    int c=0;
    try {
        CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Srijan Rana\\Desktop\\Api.csv"), ',');


while(reader.readRecord())
{
    c=c+1;
    System.out.println("Loop Counter"+c);
    Boolean br = reader.readRecord();

        if (br) {
            String[] columns = reader.getValues();
            url=columns[1];
            System.out.println("The URL is \n"+url);    
            testJson=columns[3];
            testJson=testJson.replaceAll("~", ",");

        System.out.print(testJson);

            if(columns[2].equalsIgnoreCase("POST"))

                output=(String) CommonUtil.postDataToService(url, testJson);
                else if(columns[2].equalsIgnoreCase("Get"))
                     output=(String) CommonUtil.getResponseFromService(url);


                System.out.println("Output is: "+output);
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(output);

                String val = json.getString("mobile_exist");

               assertEquals("false",val);

    }

}
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
        System.out.println(fe.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException ie) {
        System.out.println(ie.getMessage());
}

}
}
```

Comment: Hint: the rules for good design and clean code also apply for test code. In that sense: try to do **less** in one method. It is a **test**, so you really really want it to fail if something goes wrong. So "printing only" catch statements are **counter-productive**! Instead: simply throw away the catch statements - so that any exception will make JUnit fail in the end. In other words: even when you fixed that **bug** in your code; I see a dozen or more "problems" with this code. You might want to do some reviews with more experienced peers in order to fix those ...

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code as follows:

```
boolean br = reader.readRecord();
while(br)
{
    ...
    ... // remove 2nd call of `readRecord` and `if` condition
    ...
    ...
    br = reader.readRecord() // should be last line in while loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `readRecord` twice. So the first time it will read first line and second time it read second line. Meaning you are processing on alternative lines.

Example code

```
try {

        CsvReader reader= new CsvReader(file);

        while (reader.readRecord())
        {
            // logic goes here
        }

        reader.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Boolean br = reader.readRecord();   
while(br)
{
    br = reader.readRecord();
    //code
}
```

This is the code that worked for me. Thanks for your help.